# Azure - does not have authorization to perform action

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Why am I getting this error when trying to get the cost of azure subscription. I'm trying to use CURL to make a request using BEARER token and I get this error.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

```
"message":"The client '1234156-ab0b5797ef12' with object id '123456-4839-a8ce-ab0b5797ef12' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Consumption/aggregatedcost/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/stack-testing/providers/Microsoft.Consumption' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error usually occurs if your service principal doesn't have
`required permissions` or `role` to perform the specified action.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got the same error like below:***

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{managementGroupId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/aggregatedcost?api-version=2021-10-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to assign the service principal **`Billing Reader`** role like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Management groups -> Your management group -> Access control (IAM) -> Add role assignment***

[image]

After assigning that role, I am able to get the cost of azure subscription successfully.

You can also assign **`Cost Management Contributor`** or **`Cost Management Reader`** based on your requirement.

**Reference:**
[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#billing-reader)